# Tensorflow Object-Detection API - How does the Fine-Tuning of a model works?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, object-detection

This is a more general question about the Tensorflow Object-Detection API.

I am using this API, to be more concrete I fine-tune a model to my dataset. According to the description of the API, I use the `model_main.py` function to retrain a model from a given checkpoint/frozen graph.

However, it is not clear for me how the fine-tuning is working within the API. Does a re-initialization of the last layer happen automatically or do I have to implement something like ?
In the `README` files I did not find any hint concerning this topic. Maybe somebody could help me.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Training from stratch or training from a checkpoint, `model_main.py` is the main program, besides this program, all you need is a correct pipeline config file.

So for fine-tuning, it can be separated into two steps, restoring weights and updating weights. Both steps can be customly configured according to the train [proto file](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/protos/train.proto), this proto corresponds to `train_config` in the pipeline config file.

```
train_config: {
   batch_size: 24
   optimizer { }
   fine_tune_checkpoint: "PATH_TO_BE_CONFIGURED/model.ckpt"
   fine_tune_checkpoint_type:  "detection"
   # Note: The below line limits the training process to 200K steps, which we
   # empirically found to be sufficient enough to train the pets dataset. This
   # effectively bypasses the learning rate schedule (the learning rate will
   # never decay). Remove the below line to train indefinitely.
   num_steps: 200000
   data_augmentation_options {}
 }
```

**Step 1, restoring weights.**

In this step, you can config the variables to be restored by setting `fine_tune_checkpoint_type`, the options are `detection` and `classification`. By setting it to `detection` essentially you can restore almost all variables from the checkpoint, and by setting it to `classification`, only variables from the `feature_extractor` scope are restored, (all the layers in backbone networks, like VGG, Resnet, MobileNet, they are called feature extractors).

Previously this is controlled by `from_detection_checkpoint` and  `load_all_detection_checkpoint_vars`, but these two fields are deprecated.

Also notice that after you configured the `fine_tune_checkpoint_type`, the actual restoring operation would check if the variable in the graph exists in the checkpoint, and if not, the variable would be initialized with routine initialization operation.

Give an example, suppose you want to fine-tune a `ssd_mobilenet_v1_custom_data` model and you downloaded the checkpoint `ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco`, when you set `fine_tune_checkpoint_type: detection`, then all variables in the graph that are also available in the checkpoint file will be restored, and **the box predictor (last layer) weights will also be restored**. But if you set `fine_tune_checkpoint_type: classification`, then only the weights for `mobilenet` layers are restored.  But if you use a different model checkpoint, say `faster_rcnn_resnet_xxx`, then because variables in the graph are not available in the checkpoint, you will see the output log saying `Variable XXX is not available in checkpoint` warning, and they won't be restored.

**Step 2, updating weights**

Now you have all weights restored and you want to keep training (fine-tuning) on your own dataset, normally this should be enough.

But if you want to experiment with something and you want to freeze some layers during training, then you can customize the training by setting `freeze_variables`. Say you want to freeze all the weights of the mobilenet and only updating the weights for the box predictor, you can set `freeze_variables: [feature_extractor]` so that all variables that have `feature_extractor` in their names won't be updated. For detailed info, please see [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55965615/1621414) that I wrote.

So to fine-tune a model on your custom dataset, you should prepare a custom config file. You can start with the [sample config](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs) files and then modify some fields to suit your needs.

Comment: I am just trying to restore from a past checkpoint from a previous run but I only have `ckpt.meta` / `ckpt.data` and `ckpt.index` but the `fine_tune_checkpoint` field expects just one `ckpt` file?

Comment: It expects the root of the checkpoint, which is ```model.ckpt```. It then knows to look for the ```ckpt.data```, ```ckpt.index```, and ```ckpt.meta```