# how to fine tune the tensorflow object detection api model?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

I have used 300 images, in that used 80%-20% as a train and test data respectively, as per eval.py, I am getting 13 mAP%. in config batch size is 1, the number of steps is 200k, input image size is 512x512.

so what is the solution? to fine-tune only?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56012092/tensorflow-object-detection-api-how-does-the-fine-tuning-of-a-model-works) It explains how to fine tune for Object Detection API model.