# What is the difference between checkpoint_dir and fine_tune_checkpoint in tensorflow object detection?

Tags: python, tensorflow, windows-10, object-detection

I use this [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) to learn object detection on windows 10.

I prepared 400 pictures and divided them into two classes(stones and cars).

Then I used this command to train:

> cd E:\test\models-master\research\object_detection
>
> python model_main.py
>   --pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco.config --model_dir=training/ --num_train_steps=10000

In `object_detection/model_main.py` I see a parameter called `checkpoint_dir`.

But I don't know how to use `checkpoint_dir`.If my model is trained to more than 6000 steps, the `training` folder looks like the following picture:
[image]

And then I stop training the model.When I want to continue training, how to set `checkpoint_dir`?

I use this command:

> python model_main.py --pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco.config --
>   model_dir=training/ --checkpoint_dir=training/ --num_train_steps=20000  --alsologtostderr

When I added `--checkpoint_dir=training/`, the model didn't continue training. Why?How to use `--checkpoint_dir`?

I download `ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2018_01_28.tar.gz` from the [detection_model_zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md).

Then I unzipped `ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2018_01_28.tar.gz` to folder `object_detection/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2018_01_28`.

The `object_detection/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2018_01_28` folder has files like this：
[image]

So how to use `fine_tune_checkpoint` in `training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco.config`?

The content in `training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco.config` looks like this:

```
# SSD with Mobilenet v1 configuration for MSCOCO Dataset.
# Users should configure the fine_tune_checkpoint field in the train config as
# well as the label_map_path and input_path fields in the train_input_reader and
# eval_input_reader. Search for "PATH_TO_BE_CONFIGURED" to find the fields that
# should be configured.

model {
  ssd {
    num_classes: 2
    box_coder {
      faster_rcnn_box_coder {
        y_scale: 10.0
        x_scale: 10.0
        height_scale: 5.0
        width_scale: 5.0
      }
    }
    matcher {
      argmax_matcher {
        matched_threshold: 0.5
        unmatched_threshold: 0.5
        ignore_thresholds: false
        negatives_lower_than_unmatched: true
        force_match_for_each_row: true
      }
    }
    similarity_calculator {
      iou_similarity {
      }
    }
    anchor_generator {
      ssd_anchor_generator {
        num_layers: 6
        min_scale: 0.2
        max_scale: 0.95
        aspect_ratios: 1.0
        aspect_ratios: 2.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.5
        aspect_ratios: 3.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.3333
      }
    }
    image_resizer {
      fixed_shape_resizer {
        height: 300
        width: 300
      }
    }
    box_predictor {
      convolutional_box_predictor {
        min_depth: 0
        max_depth: 0
        num_layers_before_predictor: 0
        use_dropout: false
        dropout_keep_probability: 0.8
        kernel_size: 1
        box_code_size: 4
        apply_sigmoid_to_scores: false
        conv_hyperparams {
          activation: RELU_6,
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.00004
            }
          }
          initializer {
            truncated_normal_initializer {
              stddev: 0.03
              mean: 0.0
            }
          }
          batch_norm {
            train: true,
            scale: true,
            center: true,
            decay: 0.9997,
            epsilon: 0.001,
          }
        }
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: 'ssd_mobilenet_v1'
      min_depth: 16
      depth_multiplier: 1.0
      conv_hyperparams {
        activation: RELU_6,
        regularizer {
          l2_regularizer {
            weight: 0.00004
          }
        }
        initializer {
          truncated_normal_initializer {
            stddev: 0.03
            mean: 0.0
          }
        }
        batch_norm {
          train: true,
          scale: true,
          center: true,
          decay: 0.9997,
          epsilon: 0.001,
        }
      }
    }
    loss {
      classification_loss {
        weighted_sigmoid {
        }
      }
      localization_loss {
        weighted_smooth_l1 {
        }
      }
      hard_example_miner {
        num_hard_examples: 3000
        iou_threshold: 0.99
        loss_type: CLASSIFICATION
        max_negatives_per_positive: 3
        min_negatives_per_image: 0
      }
      classification_weight: 1.0
      localization_weight: 1.0
    }
    normalize_loss_by_num_matches: true
    post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 1e-8
        iou_threshold: 0.6
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 100
      }
      score_converter: SIGMOID
    }
  }
}

train_config: {
  batch_size: 10
  optimizer {
    rms_prop_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        exponential_decay_learning_rate {
          initial_learning_rate: 0.004
          decay_steps: 800720
          decay_factor: 0.95
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
      decay: 0.9
      epsilon: 1.0
    }
  }
  fine_tune_checkpoint: 'ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2018_01_28/model.ckpt'
  from_detection_checkpoint: true
  # Note: The below line limits the training process to 200K steps, which we
  # empirically found to be sufficient enough to train the pets dataset. This
  # effectively bypasses the learning rate schedule (the learning rate will
  # never decay). Remove the below line to train indefinitely.
  num_steps: 1000
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    ssd_random_crop {
    }
  }
}

train_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path:'data/train.record'
  }
  label_map_path:'data/side_vehicle.pbtxt'
}

eval_config: {
  num_examples: 8000
  # Note: The below line limits the evaluation process to 10 evaluations.
  # Remove the below line to evaluate indefinitely.
  max_evals: 10
}

eval_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: 'data/test.record'
  }
  label_map_path: 'data/side_vehicle.pbtxt'
  shuffle: false
  num_readers: 1
}
```

Are these two lines right?

> fine_tune_checkpoint: 'ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2018_01_28/model.ckpt'
>
> from_detection_checkpoint: true

What is the difference between checkpoint_dir and fine_tune_checkpoint in tensorflow object detection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functionality of `checkpoint_dir` isn't obvious by its name. This parameter lets you give a checkpoint of the model in order to evaluate it only, without any training. Indeed, if you see the help of this parameter, you'll get

> Path to directory holding a checkpoint.  If `checkpoint_dir` is
>   provided, this binary operates in eval-only mode, writing resulting
>   metrics to `model_dir`.

The fine_tune_checkpoint on the other hand is self-explanatory, and indeed lets you provide a checkpoint to fine-tune from. Note that if you don't set `fine_tune_checkpoint_type: "detection"` and `load_all_detection_checkpoint_vars: true`, then not all possible (i.e. existing and compatible) variables will be restored.

Comment: I learned some fine tune from this page:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56012092/tensorflow-object-detection-api-how-does-the-fine-tuning-of-a-model-works. That page is not recommended to use `load_all_detection_checkpoint_vars`. What should I do?Don't use `load_all_detection_checkpoint_vars`?

Comment: I don't think this is true. You can see for example the code in here for restoration of SSD model:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/meta_architectures/ssd_meta_arch.py#L1285
Specifically, look at line 1332: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/meta_architectures/ssd_meta_arch.py#L1332