# Training softmax layer in tensorflow object detection api

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, object-detection, object-detection-api

I'm trying to train an inventory-tracking application using [tensorflow object detection api](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) and I've used this [tutorial](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html#).
My image dataset is too small for training all the weights in the neural network and I want to train the few latter layers or even just the softmax layer. But I didn't find any tutorial which tells me how to declare which layers I want to train.
How can I do this?

Can anyone give me a link or github issue about this?

Comment: What is the model architecture, can you post here?

Comment: @JoãoCastilho Yes, This is called transfer learning

Comment: @JoãoCastilho I'm using the ssd_inception_v2_coco_2018_01_28 for pre-trained model

Comment: @JoãoCastilho Yes. Transfer Learning has several methods, and if you have a small dataset you can just train the last layers. because training all parameters will cause overfitting in your model

Comment: I can't help you in this, but i can share you some links that might be useful for you.

https://towardsdatascience.com/transfer-learning-picking-the-right-pre-trained-model-for-your-problem-bac69b488d16

https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-only-train-the-final-layer-of-a-Neural-Net-in-TensorFlow-that-was-already-trained

Comment: I think these two links are what you are looking for. (1) https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/2203  (2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55962158/how-to-modify-freezed-layers-in-training-using-tensorflows-object-detection-api   In short, when you want to freeze some layers, you can do it by adding freeze_variable to your config file.

Comment: Look at the config files at https://github.com/PINTO0309/TPU-MobilenetSSD/tree/master/colaboratory/gpu (with "retrain_last_few_layers" in the name). You need to find names of layers you wish to freeze (from the graph) and define the freeze_variable accordingly, like @satojkovic said.